# Using CloudForms for PHP (or similar) web development

Tags: openshift, devops

The company I work for offers a wide array of services, a lot of which involved compiled application development. A small portion of development is web software using interpreted languages like PHP, where any changes are instant.

The company has also invested in CloudForms and would like it to be used for all development environments where possible, but I am struggling to find a development pattern that works for a PHP/JS application, without adding overhead to the development process.

The main thing I can't get my head around (and can find nothing online for) is how one would manage to sync a local codebase to the remote dev server. This is simple with locally hosted VM solutions like Vagrant. A developer can just change a file and refresh the local website.

Does anyone know of a pattern for this, or CloudForms-specific tool that would support live and instant code sync? The only options we've managed to come up with is an Rsync script (we found it to be unreliable) and doing commits and pulls via GIT (terrible overhead and it means we have to commit every single change just to see if solves a given issue).

Are we better off sticking with local VM development for this sort of software if it works?